# How to aggregate calculation in SQL Server?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a following script to get the total unit but it gives me an error

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Do I need to calculate `SUM(ta.Qty)` outside the main table?

```
SELECT
    ta.ProductName
    , SUM(ta.Total)
    , SUM(SUM(ta.Qty) * ta.Unit)
FROM
    tableA tA
INNER JOIN 
    tableB tB on tA.ID = tb.TableAID
INNER JOIN 
    tableC tc on ta.ID = tc.TableAID
INNER JOIN 
    tableD td on td.ID = tb.TableBID
GROUP BY 
    ta.ProductName
```

Comment: Can you provide 1) the rest of your query, and 2) the error.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please check.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to have those SUMs nested like that. SUM(ta.Qty) is how many total ta.Qty's added together exist for one ProductName. Perhaps you could provide some example data to explain what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query in the AdventureWorks database that produces the same error (but might make some sense):

```
SELECT v.Name AS Vendor, SUM(SUM(p.ListPrice*d.OrderQty)+h.Freight)
FROM Production.Product p
INNER JOIN Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail d ON p.ProductID = d.ProductID
INNER JOIN Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader h ON h.PurchaseOrderID = d.PurchaseOrderID
INNER JOIN Purchasing.Vendor v ON v.BusinessEntityID = h.VendorID
GROUP BY v.Name
```

And here are two ways that I could rewrite that query to avoid the error:

```
SELECT v.Name AS Vendor, SUM(x.TotalAmount+h.Freight)
FROM (
    SELECT PurchaseOrderID, SUM(p.ListPrice*d.OrderQty) AS TotalAmount
    FROM Production.Product p
    INNER JOIN Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail d ON p.ProductID = d.ProductID
    GROUP BY PurchaseOrderID
) x
INNER JOIN Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader h ON h.PurchaseOrderID = x.PurchaseOrderID
INNER JOIN Purchasing.Vendor v ON v.BusinessEntityID = h.VendorID
GROUP BY v.Name

SELECT v.Name AS Vendor, SUM(x.TotalAmount+h.Freight)
FROM Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader h
INNER JOIN Purchasing.Vendor v ON v.BusinessEntityID = h.VendorID
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT SUM(p.ListPrice*d.OrderQty) AS TotalAmount
    FROM Production.Product p
    INNER JOIN Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail d ON p.ProductID = d.ProductID
    WHERE d.PurchaseOrderID=h.PurchaseOrderID
) x
GROUP BY v.Name
```

The first query uses derived tables and the second one uses CROSS APPLY.